# How keep first character but remove everything else before space in R?

Tags: r

I know how I can remove everything before a space in a character string, but I'd like to keep the first initial of a name. How can I do this so the result is `"F LastName"`? Thanks.

```
full_name <- "FirstName LastName"
sub(".*? ", "", full_name) # Removes everything before space.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-regex friendly way:

```r
spl <- strsplit(full_name, " ")[[1]]
paste(substr(spl[1], 1, 1), spl[2])
#[1] "F LastName"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub()` with a capture group we can try:

```
full_name <- "FirstName LastName"
output <- sub("([A-Z])\\w* (.*)", "\\1 \\2", full_name)
output

[1] "F LastName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `sub`.

```
sub("(.)[^ ]*", "\\1", full_name)
#[1] "F LastName"
```

`(.)` takes the first character and stores it in `\\1`, `[^ ]*` takes everything but not a space, `\\1` inserts what was at `(.)`.

Or with a look behind.

```
sub("(?<=.)[^ ]*", "", full_name, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "F LastName"
```

`(?<=.)` looks behind if there is any character `.` but does not consume it.

Benchmark

```
full_name <- rep("FirstName LastName", 1e5)
bench::mark(GKi1 =  sub("(.)[^ ]*", "\\1", full_name),
            GKi2 =  sub("(?<=.)[^ ]*", "", full_name, perl=TRUE),
            "Tim Biegeleisen" = sub("([A-Z])\\w* (.*)", "\\1 \\2", full_name),
            Mael = {spl <- strsplit(full_name, " ") #Changed that it works on vectors
              sapply(spl, \(spl) paste(substr(spl[1], 1, 1), spl[2]))}
            )
# expression           min   median itr/s…¹ mem_al…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴
#  <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>   <dbl> <bch:by>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t>
#1 GKi1              22.6ms   22.7ms   44.0   781.3KB    0       22     0   500ms
#2 GKi2              14.6ms   14.8ms   67.1   781.3KB    1.97    34     1   507ms
#3 Tim Biegeleisen   47.7ms   47.8ms   20.9   781.3KB    0       11     0   526ms
#4 Mael               430ms  446.8ms    2.24   4.06MB   32.5      2    29   894ms
```

Using `sub("(?<=.)[^ ]*", "", full_name, perl=TRUE)` is currently the fastest.